# Grunt task arguments do not work

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to configure grunt to have 2 tasks (development and production). But for whatever reason, whenever I add an argument, the task gets run (as you will see) but there is not output/action:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {  
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {           
            dev: {          
                options: {
                    // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
                    separator: ';'
                },
                dist: {
                    // the files to concatenate
                    src: [            
                        'public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'                        
                    ],
                    // the location of the resulting JS file
                    dest: 'public/js/aaaaa.src.js'
                }
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
                    separator: ';'
                },
                    dist: {
                    // the files to concatenate
                    src: [            
                        'public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'                        
                    ],
                    // the location of the resulting JS file
                    dest: 'public/js/bbbbbb.src.js'
                }
            }    
        }       
    });

    // Load Plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:dev']);
});
```

Output:

```
$ grunt
Running "concat:dev" (concat) task

Done, without errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin does not support nested targets:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {  
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {           
            dev: {          

                // the files to concatenate
                src: [            
                   'public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'                     
                ],
                 // the location of the resulting JS file
                 dest: 'public/js/aaaaa.src.js'

            },
            prod: {

                // the files to concatenate
                src: [            
                    'public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'                        
                ],
                // the location of the resulting JS file
                dest: 'public/js/bbbbbb.src.js'
                }                  
        }       
    });

    // Load Plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:dev']);
});
```